# Page breaking between introduction and abstract

Tags: page-breaking

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex61}
\pdfoutput=1 %for arXiv submission
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apjfonts} 
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}

\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref
\renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref

\shorttitle{AASTeX 6.1 Template}
\shortauthors{AUthor A. et al.}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the Paper}

\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\author{Author 3}

\affiliation{The UX}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract of this paper!
\end{abstract}
\keywords{keyword1 --- keyword2 --- keyword3}

\section{Introduction}
Intro to the paper

\section{Summary}
Summary text.

\acknowledgments
Acknowledgments.

%\facility{facility ID}
\facilities{facility ID, facility ID, facility ID} 
\software{Numpy}

\bibliographystyle{yahapj}
\bibliography{references}

\appendix
\section{appendix section}

\end{document}
```

After I use this command, in the preview section, I see my title and my abstract; but my introduction starts from a completely new page. How do I prevent this?

Here's the output:

[image: page_1]
[image: page_2]
[image: page_3]

P.S. I'm doing all of this in overleaf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add some more text to your question. What exactly is your problem? Just the code is not really clear. Also, an image of the output in question may be helpful.

Comment: I'm so sorry, LOL. After I posted my question, for some reason, some of the details went missing (I suspect it was because I created an account and it didn't autosave). Let me redit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aastex61` class defines `\section` to do

```latex
\def\section{%
\if@firstsection
      \maketitle
\global\@firstsectionfalse
     \setcounter{footnote}{\thefront@matter@foot@note}%
     \let\footnotetext=\old@foot@note@text
     \let\footnotemark=\old@foot@note@mark
   \clearpage
   \if@two@col
   \twocolumngrid
   \fi
\fi
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{9pt plus 1pt minus
    1pt}{4pt}{\apjsecfont\center}}
```

The `\if@firstsection` conditional is set to true at the beginning, so the effect of the first `\section` command is to issue `\maketitle`:

```latex
\def\frontmatter@maketitle{%
\@author@finish
\if@firstsection
  \title@column\titleblock@produce
\onecolumngrid
\else
%
\global\firstaffiltrue
 \title@column\secondtitleblock@produce
\fi
  \suppressfloats[t]%
%% Prevent these from being turned off so that
%% we can use \maketitle again for \AllAuthors.
%%
%  \let\and\relax
  \let\affiliation\@gobble
  \let\author\@gobble
%  \let\@AAC@list\@empty
%  \let\@AFF@list\@empty
%  \let\@AFG@list\@empty
%  \let\@AF@join\@AF@join@error
%  \let\email\@gobble
%  \let\@address\@empty
% \let\maketitle\relax
%  \let\thanks\@gobble
\if@firstsection
  \let\abstract\@undefined\let\endabstract\@undefined
  \titlepage@sw{%
   \vfil
   \clearpage
  }{}%
\fi
}%

\let\maketitle\frontmatter@maketitle
```

The conclusion is that the page break after the abstract (actually, after all the front matter information) has been typeset is *wanted*.

You can remove the page break by adding, before `\begin{document}`,

```latex
\makeatletter
\@booleanfalse\titlepage@sw
\makeatother
```

This no longer happens with `aastex63` (which is also on TeX Live).

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex63}
\pdfoutput=1 %for arXiv submission
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{apjfonts} 
\usepackage[figure,figure*]{hypcap}

\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref
\renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section} %for \autoref

\shorttitle{AASTeX 6.1 Template}
\shortauthors{AUthor A. et al.}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the Paper}

\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\author{Author 3}

\affiliation{The UX}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract of this paper!
\end{abstract}
\keywords{keyword1 --- keyword2 --- keyword3}

\section{Introduction}
Intro to the paper

\section{Summary}
Summary text.

\acknowledgments
Acknowledgments.

%\facility{facility ID}
\facilities{facility ID, facility ID, facility ID} 
\software{Numpy}

\bibliographystyle{yahapj}
\bibliography{references}

\appendix
\section{appendix section}

\end{document}
```

(I commented out `apjfonts` that I don't have)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552325/unwanted-page-break-after-maketitle ? I think it could work in your particular case.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, i guess {
\let\clearpage\relax
} after \end{abstract} is a valid option.